# Change Pycharm Emacs key bindings to use different word delimiter

Tags: python, emacs, pycharm

At work, I am typically only able to use bare-bones vi/emacs for various reasons. Since I'm more of an emacs fan, whenever I use a "heavier" IDE (like Pycharm) in my spare time at home, I like to set my IDEs to use emacs key bindings.

What I've noticed is that the bindings are mostly the same, and have the same functionality. There are a few exceptions, but some bindings I don't use often so it's not a big deal. However, there is one that really irritates me that I use all the time, and it is really starting to block my chakra/developer flow.

Say I have a variable named `my_var_that_represents_xyz`. If my cursor is at the beginning of the line, and I use "<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>", I expect the cursor to move to the end of the word `my`. Instead, it jumps to the end of the variable name. If my cursor is at the end of the variable, and I use "<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>", I expect the cursor to land at the front of `xyz`. Instead, it jumps to beginning of the variable name. If my cursor is at the end of this variable name, and I use "<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>", it deletes the whole variable. Instead, I'd like it to be more like what I'm used to at work, and only delete the `xyz` part (up to the last `_` in the variable name) of the `my_var_that_represents_xyz`. I tend to have long/verbose variable names, so when I accidentally nuke an entire variable when I didn't mean to, it can really slow me down. It also just surprises the crap out of me, and no one likes coding surprises.

Is there any way to change this default emacs key binding behavior to use `_` as a word delimiter so I can unblock my chakra become a better/faster coding ninja in Pycharm?

Comment: Hoping this will save someone else a headache. P.S. It is okay to answer your own questions immediately upon posting, see here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. First, open up your settings ("<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>" usually does the trick). Next, go to keymaps. You should already have emacs selected. Scroll down to "Delete Word Start". It should look something like this:

[image: pycharm_window_1]

Next, right click on "Delete to Word Start in Different 'CamelHumps' Mode" and select add keyboard shortcut. When you do this, you'll see a window pop up like this:

[image: pycharm_window_2]

Now, actually hit "<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>" on your keyboard (don't type it). You should see it pop up in the window as text. Now click okay (it will also prompt you to remove the old reference, which you'll want to do).

Rinse and repeat this process for "Move Caret to Next Word in Different 'CamelHumps' Mode" and "Move Caret to Previous Word in Different 'CamelHumps' Mode", but with the appropriate key bindings.

Also, note that you will have this same word delimiting behavior for camelCase if you use camelCase instead of snake_case.